# Deleting a folder in a zip file using the Python zipfile module

Tags: python, python-zipfile

Is it possible to delete a folder from inside a file using the ZipFile module in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Read out the rest of the archive and write it to a new zip file.